# MySQL not starting in Xampp

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, mysql, lamp

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Xampp 5.6.3-0. I cannot get the MySQL server to run. I have tried executing these commands so far (run in this order):

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/var/mysql
sudo chown -hR root/opt/lampp
```

This produced: `chown: missing operand after ‘root/opt/lampp’`

```
sudo chown -hR root:root /opt/lampp
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/var/mysql -R
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Which produced: (running this commend twice in a row produces the same result)

```
Restarting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.3-0...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...not running.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...ok.
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

But the server will still not start after this, how do I get the server to start?

**Edit:**

```
$ sudo lsof -i TCP:3306
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  1222 mysql   10u  IPv4  10907      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)`
```

and

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status
* /usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version      5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         1 day 4 hours 35 min 35 sec
```

With all this when trying to connect to phpmyadmin I get: [image: The server is not responding]

Comment: can you gives us the result of the command `lsof -i TCP:3306` and `/etc/init.d/mysql status` 
Because it really looks like MySQL works `Starting MySQL...ok`

Comment: please [edit] your question to add those informations. use `sudo lsof...` and `sudo /etc/init.d/mys....` without root permission it will not be relevant

Comment: @Kiwy The results have been put into the question itself.

Comment: "MySQL not starTing in Xampp" and "mysqld 1222 mysql 10u IPv4 10907 0t0 TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)" contradict each other. Mysql IS running.

Comment: This is cleary mention here, in the result you posted your Database is already running. In fact, what is not starting ? It is pretty unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: @Kiwy When I try to connect to it I get `The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured). `

Comment: please put all the information you add in your question not in comment, just comment to notify the update. Also explain cleary what you're trying and how.

Comment: Don't use XAMP on Linux! Use [LAMP](//help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) from the package repository! It's much better integrated with the rest of the system.

Comment: @Kiwy I have updated the question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster glad I found another person that agrees with me :-)

Comment: it seems running , as I try with my local dev virtual host (website) and connect to mysql using  [SQLyog](https://github.com/webyog/sqlyog-community/wiki/Downloads) but there is a problem with phpmyadmin , same as error above

Answer (score 6):

Stop the `mysql-server` service with

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

[image]

After that, just start `mysql` from `xampp`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Actually that worked for me just fine. I think the actual MySql and Apache we installed on our system were having some conflict with the XAmpp's apache and mysql. That's why we need to stop the already installed one so that the XAMPP's one start working.;)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the mysql installed in ubuntu takes over the port which will inturn block the mysql of xampp. try removing mysql completely from ubuntu and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I realised that you can't start and use MySQL from XAMPP while it is running. I think you have to stop it first (not using XAMPP command)

Comment: Can you expend on this a bit more. To me this is unclear what you want me to do.

Comment: In my case, i totaly uninstalled mysql package because it was running and preventing mysql from xampp to run.

Answer (score 0):

Open phpMyAdmin>config.inc.php in your favourite text editor.

Search for:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

Replace it with:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

cookie ;) "essa eu garantio"

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete pid files

```
$XAMPP_ROOT/logs/httpd.pid
$XAMPP_ROOT/var/mysql/$(hostname).pid
$XAMPP_ROOT/var/proftpd.pid
```